# Is there a big difference between Yellow and Yukon Gold potatoes?

Tags: potatoes

After moving to Canada six months ago, I still haven't found Yukon Gold potatoes at the grocery stores. Instead I find Yellow potatoes and was curious as to whether or not they are considered to be the same or if they are completely different. I find that the texture is a little bit "harder" than the Yukon Gold potatoes but overall seem pretty similar. So, are Yellow potatoes the same as Yukon Gold and can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are often used interchangeably.  The truth is, yukon gold potatoes are a type of yellow potato.  They were developed in Canada.  You will definitely see them on store shelves here in Canada, but it can be seasonal, depending on your location.  I am in Winnipeg, and I find YG about six months of the year.

Comment: I live in the Maritimes and I have yet to see them in stores, but I shall keep my eye out for them. I had had the feeling that they were developed in the Yukon Territories, hence the name. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I guess that was a little obvious.  Here in Manitoba, we grow a lot of russets and yukon golds, our soil lends itself to those varietals.  Can't speak to their availability in the far East.  However, they are very similar, so as long as you can get yellow potatoes, you should be OK.  Although, I must admit, I find the yukons to be just a bit nicer myself.

Answer (score 1):

Look for Maine Carola Potatoes. They are the closest to the actual Yukon in both flavor and texture. Maine grows lots of Yellow White and Russet potatoes. I'm willing to bet that some stores in the maritime have the Carola Potatoes.

Answer (score 0):

In Ontario I find that yellow potatoes are not the same as Yukon gold! Yukons have a different texture and cook differently. I can't find them right now (late September) and am disappointed. Hope they are available soon!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the differences are in texture and cooking? (Does one take longer, not hold its shape as well, etc.?)